# Image resized by HTML way sharper than by PhotoShop

Tags: html, photoshop

I apologize if this is not the correct community to ask, but I believe this has to do with HTML so I'm asking here.

I need a small banner with credit card icons (21px high).

I made it in PS and resized it to 21px height (auto width), but I wasn't satisfied with the sharpness.

I now load the full image in HTML and using `height` and `width` image tag attributes resize it to the same size I did in PS, but the result is much better.
[image] 
1) Resized with HTML 
2) Resized with PS

Chrome developer tool shows that both of the images are the same dimensions.

Why is there such a difference?

Comment: What resampling did you use? If you resized with Ctrl+Alt+I, you were given the option of resampling. There are a few options, and some are best for increasing or decreasing size. My guess is that you used buibic sharper instead of smoother or vice versa.

Comment: @Lincoln Hmm, I did use Ctrl+Alt+I but left it on automatic

Comment: Try specifying, in my experience, automatic doesn't work as well as the more specialized options.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing many times - I've Also tried different resizing/resampling techniques (all possible in Photoshop Elements), but always ended up with a Better result when I let the browser do the resize. My Best Guess is that the browser treats the "small image" differently than PS while Being Better at placing the pixels in the most optimal way for the browser itself, when having the chance to do the resampling/optimization from (originally) more pixels . Although it even sounds strange to me Should it be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers just display it as it would be **21px** high, but higher dpi screens may use the full image to make it sharper. As in the screenshot you shared, both rows are actually **~90px** high. `Height` doesn't actually resize the image itself, it just stretchs it to a smaller area.

> Tip: Downsizing a large image with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the large image (even if it looks small on the page). To avoid this, rescale the image with a program before using it on a page.

*From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp)*

Comment: Yes but I've read that the reason image quality is lost when an image is downsized is because there are fewer pixels - since both are displayed at the same size whether resized in Photoshop or with CSS, they should have the same amount of pixels in the area that's displayed, right? Plus both images are viewed on a screen with the same dpi - so why the difference in quality? Why can't we keep the quality of and image resized by CSS by resizing with a program like Photoshop?